# ASP.NET Controller FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api, controller

In Postman, I'm sending the following JSON via a POST to API.

```
{
"id": "21",
"crgName": "Walgreens - 11/07/2018 - Standard ",
"crgStarteddatetime": "2018-11-07T10:11:10",
}
```

...but, I get the following error: **FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Inside my controller, I'm using  DateTimeFormat to format the date time:

```
 public static RemoteContextType DeserializeJsonString<RemoteContextType>(string jsonString)
        {
            //create an instance of generic type object
            RemoteContextType obj = Activator.CreateInstance<RemoteContextType>();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString));

            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType(),
                new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    DateTimeFormat = new

                             DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'")
                });

            obj = (RemoteContextType)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

            ms.Close();

            return obj;
           }
```

...is there an issue in my syntax as to how I have the Date formatted? My intentions are to formate the date as it is reflected in the JSON. Could I get some help as to what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'")
```

You're specifying the format exactly as UTC/Zulu datetime with `'Z'` format specifier and 3 digits of seconds fraction ([`fff` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-fff-custom-format-specifier)), but the value used in `crgStarteddatetime` doesn't have both of them (i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`).

Based on the JSON example, you should change the format to match exactly as provided in `crgStarteddatetime`:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType(), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
                 {
                     DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                 });
```

If actual JSON data of `crgStarteddatetime` has mixed date formats (some of the dates have `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` and others may have `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`), use [`K` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-k-custom-format-specifier) which is more flexible to handle timezone format:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType(), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
                 {
                     DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK")
                 });
```

Comment: Thank you, I greatly appreciate your help